# Exercise #5 Chapter 6 of Programming in C

Tags: c

> Write a program that acts as a simple "printing" calculator. The program should allow the user to type in expressions of the form: number operator. The following operators should be recognized by the program: +, -, *, /, S. E
>
> - The S operator tells the program to set the "accumulator" to the typed-in number.
> - The E operator tells the program that execution is to end.The arithmetic operations are performed on the contents of the accumulator with the number that was keyed in acting as the second operand.
>
> The following is a "sample run" showing how the program should operate:
>
> ```
> Begin Calculations
>     10 S            Set Accumulator to 10 
>     = 10.000000     Contents of Accumulator
>     2 /             Divide by 2 
>     = 5.000000      Contents of Accumulator
>     55 -            Subtract 55 
>     -50.000000
>     100.25 S        Set Accumulator to 100.25 
>     = 100.250000
>     4 *             Multiply by 4 
>     = 401.000000
>     0 E             End of program 
>     = 401.000000
> End of Calculations.
> ```

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char op;
float acc = 0, num;

printf("Begin Calculations\n");
while (op != 'E') {
    scanf("%f %c", &num, &op);
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            acc += num;
            printf("= %f\n", acc);
            break;
        case '-':
            acc -= num;
            printf("= %f\n", acc);
            break;
        case '*':
            acc *= num;
            printf("= %f\n", acc);
            break;
        case '/':
            if (num == 0) {
                printf("Division by zero\n");
            }
            else {
                acc /= num;
                printf("= %f\n", acc);
            }
            break;
        case 'S':
            acc = num;
            printf("= %f\n", acc);
            break;
        case 'E':
            printf("= %f\n", acc);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unknown operator\n");
            break;
    }
}
printf("End of Calculations");
}
```

My code work perfectly with the question input. However, when I input the following (and the output) (same input as question but without space between "number" and "operator"):

```
Begin Calculations
    10S            
    = 10.000000    
    2/            
    = 5.000000      
    55-            
    -50.000000
    100.25S        
    = 100.250000
    4*            
    = 401.000000
    0E
```

The program stuck when I input 0E. I have tried to change `scanf("%f %c", &num, &op);` to `scanf("%f%c", &num, &op);` but it didn't seem to solve my problem. Could you point out the problem in my code? Please give me a detail explaination because I'm relative new to C. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You have *undefined behavior*. The value of uninitialized non-static local variables, like your `op` variable, is *indeterminate*. You need to initialize it before you use it in the loop condition. Either that, or change to a `do-while` loop.

Comment: The problem is that `0E` isn't a valid number, but `0E12` would be.  The implementation probably rejects it and leaves the input behind.  _Always_ check the return value from `scanf()`.  When it isn't what you expect, you have to go into 'error recovery' mode, which might mean 'abandon ship' (exit the program) or 'read the line that failed; say it failed; make the user have another go'.  Alternatively, the code may have accepted the `0E` as a number and is sitting there waiting for the non-blank character for the `%c`; try typing `E` again.

Comment: I may be missing something, but i think UB is caused by `while (op != 'E')`. The reasoin is the same - variable `op` is uninitialized. By the time switch statement comes `op` should contain something, if of course scanf executed correctly.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have tried to initialized `op` variable and use the `do-while` loop but it didn't fix the problem.    
                                
@JonathanLeffler But why if the input is `10S`, `0M`,... the program still work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading a float value. So if scanf sees 0E, it awaits more digits as it thinks you are inputting an exponential as e.g. 0E5 (=0*10^5). That's why your program gets stuck at this point. I would suggest to use a different character to end to avoid this ambiguity.

If, on the other hand, scanf sees 0S, it will output 0.0 as float value and 'S' as character, as 'S' is never a valid part of a float value.

Comment: Thanks you very much. By changing to a character different than 'e' and 'E' fixed my problem. I forgot about the e in float number.

Comment: So would you mind marking it as correct answer? Thank you!